# Como setar uma variável na primeira chamada a uma função, e manter esse valor na segunda chamada em diante

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Tenho uma função que seta uma variável após percorrer uma lista extensa, o que demanda um certo tempo. O programa chama essa função outras vezes, porque ela é responsável pelo preenchimento de um formulário. Depois dessa variável setada na primeira vez, ele não precisa mais percorrer a lista de novo, ou seja, o tempo gasto da primeira vez não precisa ser perdido de novo. Essa variável equivale ao preenchimento de um determinado campo desse formulário. Como fazer o programa "lembrar" do valor dela da segunda vez em diante?

```
def SetaConsulta(): #Essa consulta cria a lista dos processos com prazo em status "aguardando abertura".
    menu = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('ms-choice')
    menu[0].click()
    opcoes = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('label')
    localidade = browser.find_element_by_id('selIdLocalidade')
    for x in range(len(opcoes)):
        if opcoes[x].text == "Curitiba":
            curitiba = x
        if opcoes[x].text == "Paranaguá":
            paranagua = x
    opcoes[curitiba].click() #Seleciona Curitiba na lista.
    opcoes[paranagua].click() #Seleciona Paranagua na lista.
    grau = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('selGrauJudicial'))
    grau.select_by_index(1)
    prazo = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('selPrazo'))
    prazo.select_by_index(1)
    dtInicio = browser.find_element_by_id('txtDataInicio')
    dtInicio.send_keys(dataInicio)
    dtFim = browser.find_element_by_id('txtDataTermino')
    dtFim.send_keys(dataFim) #dataFim
    inclusao = browser.find_element_by_id('selInclusaoProcurador')
    opcoesInclusao = inclusao.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
    checkbox1 = browser.find_element_by_id('optChkPoloOposto')
    testeCheckbox1 = browser.find_element_by_id('optChkPoloOposto').is_selected()
    if testeCheckbox1 == False:
        checkbox1.click()
    checkbox2 = browser.find_element_by_id('optChkProcuradoresAssociados')
    testeCheckbox2 = browser.find_element_by_id('optChkProcuradoresAssociados').is_selected()
    if testeCheckbox2 == False:
        checkbox2.click()
    checkbox3 = browser.find_element_by_id('optChkExibirApensos')
    testeCheckbox3 = browser.find_element_by_id('optChkExibirApensos').is_selected()
    if testeCheckbox3 == False:
        checkbox3.click()
    checkbox4 = browser.find_element_by_id('optChkCpfCnpjSeparado')
    testeCheckbox4 = browser.find_element_by_id('optChkCpfCnpjSeparado').is_selected()
    if testeCheckbox4 == False:
        checkbox4.click()
    botao = browser.find_element_by_id('btnConsultar')
    botao.click()
    time.sleep(8)
    MontaDados()
```

Me refiro às variáveis "curitiba" e "paranagua" da função acima, que são selecionadas num menu dropdown dentre vários checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar variáveis globais `curitiba` e `paranagua`, da seguinte forma:

```
curitiba = -1
paranagua = -1

def SetaConsulta(): #Essa consulta cria a lista dos processos com prazo e...
    ....
```

Mais tarde, antes de:

```
        for x in range(len(opcoes)):
            if opcoes[x].text == "Curitiba":
                curitiba = x
            if opcoes[x].text == "Paranaguá":
                paranagua = x
```

coloque:

```
    if curitiba == -1 and paranagua == -1:
```

Comment: Eu tinha feito isso, mas não tinha dado certo... mas tinha setado elas com "None".

Comment: Pode ser também, mas daí o teste tem que ser `if curitiba is None and paranagua is None:`